# How would you accomplish this warp/distort/liquify effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, distort, glitch

Mainly asking about the head image, not the animated texture effect.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose your images, these are from unsplash.com [(1)](https://unsplash.com/photos/h5cd51KXmRQ), [(2)](https://unsplash.com/photos/thUe_ZOrOy4)

Menu **Image** → **Mode** → **Grayscale**

[image]

Menu **Image** → **Adjustment** → **Threshold**

[image]

Select just the half of each image and scale horizontally

[image]

Use the **Eraser** and **Brush tool** to join them and merge the layers

[image]

Select just the central part and add the effect: **Menu Filter** → **Distort** → **Wave**

[image]

Use mask and brushes to finish it

[image]